# Android: Convert Integer for Set Color. Is This Possible to Do It?

Tags: android, textview, android-view, android-background, android-color

I have a question about Set Background Color for a View programmatically.

> I have integer value that I would like to use for background color for TextView. Now I have the Integer values of 
>   **-8076976**

Is this possible to use this value to convert for be able to use background color?

Thank you very much

**Edit**
The integer value can be changed because of I used a seek bar that for picking color so that I would like to know convert the integer value and directly set as background color.

Comment: R u sure its a negative value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Color.xml file create a color item with this color followed by a #.
Then in your code use:

```
  getResources.getColor(R.color.color-code);
```

Update:

As per your comment you want to show directly the hex value.
Look at the code here:

```
 SetBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Replace with your own hex color code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to set background color without using Color.xml file because of the integer value can be changed. Do you have any idea of not using Color.xml and set background color from integer values? Thank you

Comment: You can do that easily through xml. Why dont you use that way?

Comment: I got the integer value from color picker seeker bar, so that the integer value is  changeable. Thank you